# Can I have two sudo users for the same linux machine?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am working on ubuntu. 
I have one superuser called hduser and another user called hadoopuser where I have installed hadoop and working on it. 
My question is where should I install the other softwares hive & pig. Because when I install pig everything works fine, the loading data and everything, but when I dump the variable to print the output then I am getting exception

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hduser, access=WRITE, inode="":hadoopuser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias amt
```

Can I have hadoopuser & hduser  as both superusers ? 
How could I solve this problem?

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can login to root user using **sudo -s** command. And can make all your installations from root. Hope it helps!